# Triggering a Subject in Angular once user finishes Typing

Tags: javascript, rxjs, subject

I want to trigger an ajax request when the user has finished typing in a text box. I don't want it to run the function on every time the user types a letter because that would result in A LOT of ajax requests, however I don't want them to have to hit the enter button either.

Is there a way so I can detect when the user has paused typing, say a pause of 500ms.

I tried using the debounce but the debounce time increases automatically after a few calls.

I tried to make a call once the user has paused typing for a time of 500ms but the debounce function which I used is increasing the timer exponentially.

Comment: Can you please add any code you tried with debounce?

Comment: of(data).pipe(
      // filter(parameter => parameter.value.trim().length > 0),
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged((pre: any, curr: any) => pre.value == curr.value),
      switchMap(parameter => {
               //logic goes here
}))

Answer (score 1):

This is working code::

app.component.html

```
<p>app component</p>

<input
  class="form-control"
  type="text"
  name="search"
  #search
  (input)="this.searchUpdate.next(search.value)"
/>
```

app.component.ts::

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, Subject, switchMap } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  searchUpdate = new Subject<string>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchUpdate
      .pipe(debounceTime(400), distinctUntilChanged(), switchMap(value => {
        // perform your ajax logic here
      }))
      .subscribe((value) => {
        console.log(value);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this logic and this doesn't work

Comment: Can you please deploy code on stackblitz and share link so that I can check it?